# Error when trying to select a random dictionary entry: cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When trying to select a random word and its description from a Javascript object `WORDS`, unfortunately an error is printed:

```js
"use strict";

const WORDS = {
  "one": "Word description 1",
  "two": "Word description 2",
  "three": "Word description 3",
  "four": "",
  "five": "Word description 5",
  "six": "Word description 6",
  "seven": "Word description 7"
};

function randomWord() {
  // select all words with a description
  const entries = Object.entries(WORDS)
    .filter((word, description) => description && description.length > 2);

  console.log(entries);

  // a quicker way of doing parseInt(entries.length * Math.random(), 0)
  const [word, description] = entries[entries.length * Math.random() << 0];
  console.log(word + ': ' + description);
}

randomWord();
randomWord();
```

Here the same code in a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/Lx7h5sw2/).

Isn't using a combination of [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the right approach here?

Comment: object.entries destructure like `[key,value]` so `([word, description])`  in the filter

Comment: Your suggestion `const entries = Object.entries(WORDS).filter(([word, description]) => description && description.length > 2);` has worked, thank you.

Comment: yeah Object.entries give an array of arrays each element look like [key,value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, you have a syntax error in your filter.

Here is a working version using [Fisher-Yates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984542/295783) to shuffle the filtered array after which you can just get entries until the array is empty

```js
const fy = (a,b,c,d) => {c=a.length;while(c)b=Math.random()*c--|0,d=a[c],a[c]=a[b],a[b]=d}

const WORDS = {
  "one": "Word description 1",
  "two": "Word description 2",
  "three": "Word description 3",
  "four": "",
  "five": "Word description 5",
  "six": "Word description 6",
  "seven": "Word description 7"
};

// Use object entries array and filter it
let entries = Object.entries(WORDS)
  .filter(([word, description]) => description && description.length > 2);

if (entries.length) {
  fy(entries); // Shuffle the entries array
}

const getWord = (entries) => entries.length > 0 ? entries.pop() : "No more entries";

console.log(getWord(entries));
console.log(getWord(entries));
```